# How are Perl's lexically-scoped pragmas implemented?

Tags: perl, scope, internals, lexical-scope, compiler-directives

Pragmas, like `autodie`, according to the docs, are lexically scoped.

```
{
use autodie;
  ..
  ..
}
# Can die here
```

Does this apply to all modules loaded with `use`?
As far as I know, `use` is almost the same as:

```
BEGIN {
  require autodie;
  autodie->import(LIST);
}
```

`BEGIN` happens at compile time, and require is not lexically scoped.  So how is `autodie` aware of its scope?

Comment: Is there something you wanted to do? Or is this purely out of curiosity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is that lexically-scoped [pragmatic modules](http://p3rl.org/pragma) are explicitly written to behave that way, and use the magical internal variables [`$^H`](http://p3rl.org/var#%24%5eH) and [`%^H`](http://p3rl.org/var#%25%5eH) during compile time to enable and disable features.

The compiler plays its part by implicitly localising these variables so their value is restored at the end of compiling a code block to what it was at the start. In that way it provides the basis of lexical semantics.

Originally only the `$^H` variable was available. It contains a bit mask that dictates which compiler options are available at any time during the compilation. Because of that the only lexical pragmas that could be written were ones that manipulated the defined set of magic bits in `$^H`.

Later the `%^H` hash was introduced, and any pragma can now store values in this hash with keys that start with the name of the pragma. Because the compiler localises the hash in the same way as the scalar, any pragma can store automatically scoped status information here.

The `autodie` module doesn't manipulate either of these variables, but subclasses the [`Fatal`](http://p3rl.org/Fatal) module which does all the hard work. It uses `%^H` to keep track of which operators have been made fatal, and relies on the compiler to discard this information at the end of the block.

Answer (score 8):

From the import method of `Fatal.pm` which is the backend of `autodie`, enjoy this:

```
# Dark magic to have autodie work under 5.8
# Copied from namespace::clean, that copied it from
# autobox, that found it on an ancient scroll written
# in blood.

# This magic bit causes %^H to be lexically scoped.
$^H |= 0x020000;
```

So the answer is there really is a way to make your imports aware of their lexical scope, but it's deeply entangled with the guts of perl and not meant for ordinary programmers to use.

Comment: No, it explains only the extra step needed to make `%^H`-based pragmas work in 5.8, not just 5.10+.

Comment: yeah, I really only showed the most scary piece of it to convey a general feel for the magic involved. It was an answer in the sense that it confirmed the questioner's feeling that lexical pragmas can't be implemented with "normal" module import techniques.

Comment: but that's completely wrong...they can easily be so implemented.  see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpragma.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not `require` that's interesting; it's what the pragma does in `import`.

Most (all?) pragmas use `$^H` or `%^H`. The parser localises these to the scope being parsed, meaning it restores them to the value they had before

Take [strict](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?strict), for example. Its `import` modifies `$^H`. `$^H` contains a series of flags that instructs the compiler how to behave.

```
$ perl -e'
    BEGIN { printf "%04X\n", $^H }
    {
       use strict;
       BEGIN { printf "%04X\n", $^H }
    }
    BEGIN { printf "%04X\n", $^H }
'
0100
0702
0100
```

`$^H` is reserved for Perl's usage, but similarly localised `%^H` is available for general use. For example, [feature::qw_comment](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?feature%3a%3aqw_comments) hooks into the parser once, when it's loaded by `require`, but doesn't do anything unless `$^H{'feature::qw_comments::'}` is true. It's import is equivalent to

```
sub import { $^H{'feature::qw_comments::'} = 1; }
```